# Could anyone identify this plant for me?

Tags: identification

My mother bought this plant and has no idea about it's characteristics and the name, she would love some help in identifying it so that she could care for it correctly.

I would really appreciate any help!
Thanks so much in advance.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'll take a stab and suggest Eucalyptus parvula (previously E. parvifolia), maybe?

Comment: Do the leaves have a menthol like smell when crushed?  That would confirm Bamboo's guess.

Comment: I'll ask my Mom to crush and smell it. I'll post here again after I hear back. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe Conocarpus erectus v sericeus. Silver Buttonwood. Where was the plant purchased? Silver Buttonwood is native to south florida. Typically a small-medium sized tree to 25', often pruned to a 3-6' hedge. Prefers full sun, tolerant of light shade, fairly easy to maintain. Fruit is a cone like. Check link, http://lee.ifas.ufl.edu/Hort/GardenPubsAZ/Buttonwood.pdf